# How to get array return from callback function in F2PY?

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I'm trying to write a little interface from Python to Fortran with F2PY, where an array gets passed to a callback function in Python and the resulting array gets passed back to Fortran.
I have the following Fortran code:

```
      Subroutine myscript(x,fun,o,n)
      external fun
      integer n
      real*8 x(n)
cf2py intent(in,copy) x
cf2py intent(out) o
cf2py integer intent(hide),depend(x) :: n=shape(x,0)
cf2py function fun(n,x) result o
cf2py integer intent(in,hide) :: n
cf2py intent(in), Dimension(n), depend(n) :: x
cf2py end function fun
      o = fun(n,x)
      write(*,*) o
      end
```

where fun is a callback function in Python which looks like this:

```
def f(x):
    print(x)
    return x
```

Now when I wrap the Fortran code with F2PY and run it from Python, e.g. like this:

```
myscript.myscript(numpy.array([1,2,3]),f)
```

I get the following result:

```
[1. 2. 3.]
1.00000000
```

So apparently the array gets passed through to the callback function f but then when it gets passed back only the first entry is preserved.
What do I need to do to get the whole array back? i.e. get the variable o in the Fortran Code to contain the array [1.,2.,3.] instead of just 1.?

Comment: `o` isn't declared as an array, nor `fun` to have an array result, in the Fortran code.

Comment: After some playing with it I am not sure if such functions are supported by f2py. When I added an interface block, it did not compile with some cryptic error when compiling the C wrapper.

Comment: BTW you declare `cf2py intent(in), Dimension(n), depend(n) :: x` but in the subroutine `x` is `real*8 x(n)`, that is another problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally figured it out. As pointed out, `o` has to be declared and then `o` has to be put into the function `fun` too. The function then has to be called with Fortran's `call` statement (as opposed to `o = fun(n,x)`). Apparently, one can also get rid of most of the `cf2py` statements. Interestingly, `fun` does not have to explicitly be declared as a function with array return. The following code works for me:

```
      Subroutine myscript(x,fun,o,n)
      external fun
      integer n
      real*8 x(n)
      real*8 o(n)
cf2py intent(in,copy), depend(n) :: x
cf2py intent(hide) :: n
cf2py intent(out), depend(n) :: o
      call fun(n,x,o)
      write(*,*) o
      end
```

It returns

```
[1. 2. 3.]
1.00000000 2.00000000 3.00000000
```

Comment: Perhaps a simple clarification could be: replace the function with an array result with a subroutine?